# How to safely generate external links?

Tags: asp.net-core, url, href

I would like to create an HTML link in my view, which leads to an offsite site and has a dynamic URL component.

I tried this:

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/@item.Title">
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
</a>
```

where `item.Title` is a dynamic string. If I use `@item.Title` it is safely HTML encoded, but it is not url encoded. So if the string contains `/` for example my URL will be broken. How can I URL encode it? Is there a tag helper that can generate the link for me?

Comment: Just URL encode `@item.Title`

Comment: @DavidG Is there a function for that?

Comment: Can't remember off the top of my head, but try `Url.Encode(...)`?

Comment: I used `@Uri.EscapeDataString(item.Title)` Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use  [System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.urlencode?view=netcore-3.1) in razor like:

```
@{ 
    var title = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(item.Title);
}
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/@title">
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)

</a>
```